# Palindrome Checker - can't get the function to check the phrase

Tags: javascript, css, html

My Palindrome checker function works for single strings i.e. 'dog' it works, but when it is a phrase i.e. 'nurses run' it does not work! here is my code:

```
function palindromeCheck(string) {
  return string === string.split('').reverse().join('');

}
```

Comment: Strip the spaces?

Comment: Apologies 
I just edited it, it didn't relate at all, and what do you mean when you say strip the spaces ?

Comment: Before you do your check, remove the spaces from the input string. So for example, instead of checking `nurses run` you check `nursesrun`

Answer (score 3):

```
function palindromeCheck(string) {
  string = string.replace(/\s+/g,'');
  return string === string.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

The **s+** character means to match any number of whitespace characters (including tabs). The **g** character means to repeat the search through the entire string.  Read about this, and other RegEx modifiers available in JavaScript [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

Comment: I suggest using `/\s+/g` as your regex to catch 1 or more of any whitespace character

Comment: Can you suggest a case in which `/ /g` fails to produce the expected result? I tested a few case scenarios and it appears to work as expected. http://i.imgur.com/BHAWnU5.png

Comment: I believe a tab would not be caught (if that's even possible in a string). I could be also very wrong, but I see it as a slight efficiency boost by matching and replacing as many characters at a time: so 2 spaces would make one replacement and `/ /g` would make 2 replacements

Comment: Oh I see, you're right. Tabs are not caught with `/ /g`. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
function palindromeCheck(string) {
  string = string.replace(/\s/g, "");
  return string === string.split('').reverse().join('');

}

console.log(palindromeCheck('nurses run'))
```

Comment: Thank you! this works, would you mind explaining how this works?

Comment: the replace() is replacing all spaces with nothing...in short, it is removing spaces and then your code for palindrome works perfectly

Comment: Awesome thank you, that is fantastic thank you for your time!

Comment: I am glad I could help you.

Comment: `string.replace(' ', '')` only removes the first space. For example, this will return false for the string "a man a plan a canal panama". You need to use a regular expression with the g flag to remove all of them like in [Dragoş' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43943539/2214).